# How do I deploy an Azure bicep file from a Azure functions app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-bicep

I want to be able to call an http trigger on an Azure Function app, to trigger a deployment of other resources in azure.

- Is it possible to deploy Azure Bicep files from an Azure Function app?
- Eg. If I use a powershell function, could I preconfigure it with "Bicep CLI" or "Azure CLI" in some way?

Comment: you can use azure powershell to deploy bicep as per documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-powershell

Comment: Yes, but if I use a azure functions app with powershell, do I need to install Bicep CLI on the functions app? 
Because Powershell normally wont come with Bicep CLI installed. But I'm not shure about the powershell setup in function app. And if it's not preconfigured with Bicep CLI, is it possible to preconfigure it in the functions app?

Comment: it is already included in latest version of az powershell module. gitve it try first tbh

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly, what you want is to use a Function App to trigger a deployment, so why don't you set up a release pipeline and trigger it from the Function App instead?